# Programatically add constraint to prevent button overlap SWIFT 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, constraints

I was wondering if someone could help me with programatically constraints. What I want is:

I create buttons inside a loop and the buttons are aligned horizontally next to each other. Some of the buttons have different widths, so that means that a button can overlap to another button. Is is possible to use constraint to prevent the overlapping and add a white space in between?

Thanks in advance

Code:

```
        for (j, _) in buttonInfo.enumerated(){
        let button: UIButton = buttonArray[j]
        let stackView = UIStackView();

        stackView.spacing = 30;


        button.tag = Int((buttonInfo[j]?.pID)!)!
        button.setTitle(buttonInfo[j]?.title, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PalletViewController.productCall), for: .touchUpInside)

        let stock = Int(buttonInfo[j]!.stock)

        if(stock! == 0 || stock! < 0){
            button.isHidden = true;
        }


        let views = ["view": view, "button": button] as [String : Any]





        let spacing = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-(10)-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views);

        view.addConstraints(spacing);


    }
```

Comment: You should take a look at the [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview)

Comment: Suggestions is Don't add constraints in a loop, you can add these buttons in a dictionary while looping, and then when the loop ends, just add this `[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[button]-(5)-[button]-(5)-[button]--|" options:0 metrics:nil views:nil];` to the buttons' parent view, finally these buttons get a white space is `5` or what your want

Comment: @VictorJohn Hi vic, I get the following error when using this code: `let views = ["view": view];              NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat:"H:|-[button]-(5)-[button]-(5)-‌​[button]--|",options:NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views)`         `reason: Unable to parse constraint format: It's an empty string.`

Comment: show me your code, so that I can find the problem @LifeOS

Comment: @VictorJohn edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack view is best option, you can create it programmatically also. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html